# installing twiki on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, twiki

I want to install twiki on ubuntu server , http://mysite.com/docs/bin/configure is returning the configure file itself .

I renamed the twiki folder to docs .

How can I configure twiki, and why the file is coming in browser?

Please help .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following URL for installing twiki on ubuntu and make sure you haven't missed any steps

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=219213

http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.06/Wiki/index.html

Comment: i had followed ubuntuforum thread already :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try apt-get install twiki (i am not sure it will work on sevrver but it worked for me on ubuntu 9.10 desktop edition)